# how to use fullcalendar events as a variables?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fullcalendar

hello i'm using fullcalendar and i want to declare `event.start` and `event.end` as a variable to use it inside my PHP code like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM chambre
         WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id_chambre 
                          FROM reservation_client 
                          WHERE start <= event.end 
                            AND end >= event.start)";
```

`event.start` and `event.end` are the two date that i select.
is it possible to mix between JavaScript and php like this?

Comment: You need to pass the variables to PHP, by POST or GET.

Comment: You may find https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed to be useful reading as well, in the particular case of fullCalendar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mix client side code (JavaScript) and server side code (PHP).
With JavaScript, you can only access resources at the client (your Browser), not on the server.

I suggest making an Ajax call with parameters event.start and event.end.
Then on the Sever make a php script to check the availability of the date and return the result back to the client, Example for Ajax-request:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

You have to modify the data to your requests.

The PHP-Example:

```
$name =  $_POST['name'];
...
// do your query to the db
// return the result:
echo json_encode($results);
```

Adjust the script to your needs.

Comment: can you please explaine this by give me a script because i dont know how to do it ?

Comment: It should be noted that this example uses jQuery for the AJAX call. If you don't wish to use jQuery, then use fetch() instead.